# KineticJS: Add shape to layer and draw almost crashes browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm fairly new to `Canvas` and also KineticJS.

I tried KineticJS as I stumbled upon it several times when Googeling for answers on different issues, and found that it is good for 2D games which I am making.

The game is driving game, but the car behaves like Snake but with infinite length. My proof of concept works fine with vanilla `canvas` but when I use the KineticJS layers and add the shapes that makes the snake shape, the browser nearly crashes after 20-30 seconds...

**I have a layer for the car:**

```
var carLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(carLayer);
```

**Every 10ms I get the direction of the car, and I draw a new circle on the layer:**

```
var drawCarPoint = function(x, y) {
    var newCarSection = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        radius: 5,
        fill: 'magenta'
    });

    carLayer.add(newCarSection);
    carLayer.drawScene();
};
```

If I don't use the `drawScene()` function, nothing is drawn.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may need to draw the stage each time you add a circle to the layer. So, did you try replacing `carLayer.drawScene()` with the following :

```
stage.add(carLayer);
stage.draw();
```